# Json above 10 MB is not correctly parsed by jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

My test in jmeter have these steps:

1. generate data => many objects with same keys, but various values - output is in json file
2. take json file with http parser and with json extractor extract particular part of the json => save into variable (I'm using counter, so the data are always used from new object)
3. send variable to api

What is the issue. When the output json file contains 900 objects ( and the size of file is below 10 MB ), then the test runs and works as requested.

When I generate json file with 1000 objects and therefore the file size is more than 10MB, the step 3 never go through. When I check the response body in Listener, the response body does not contain the all data from json file and in jmeter.log is this message:

> JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor,
> message: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected End Of
> File position 10485759: null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for reading the JSON file from the file system you might suffer from the response limit of 10 megabytes, the setting responsible for the maximum supported response size is [**httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) and it used to be 10 megabytes prior to [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3)

If you want to disable this limit - just add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=0
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Comment: I set this property into the user.properties file, but it caused, that even smaller files weren't processed. I found same setting in jmeter.properties file, but uncommenting that one also caused the same thing. I also increased HEAP in jmeter.bat, just in case.

Comment: What helped was to set value above 10MB. Thanks